# Compound operator with shift in C or how to convert 20bit 2'complement number in 32bit signed int

Tags: c++

There is 20 bit 2'complement number (which is read with 3 x 8 bit) and it needs to be converted in 32bit signed int.

Could someone please explain this piece of code:

```
int32_t sample = 0;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample /= 1L << 12;
```

So now in 32bit signed integer from right the right side there is 24 values and then:

```
sample /= 1L << 12;
```

How this works?

Link for the full code is at:

https://github.com/circuitar/Nanoshield_LoadCell/blob/master/src/Nanoshield_LoadCell.cpp

Comment: It's shorthand for `sample = sample / (1L << 12)`; `sample` is being divided by `0x00001000`.  The `L` suffix forces the compiler to treat the `1` as a `long` rather than an `int`.

Comment: What is the return type of` SPI.transfer()` I guess it is an 8-bit unsigned integer type? Also this code is really C++, not C, although the arithmetic operations are probably the same.

Comment: Each `sample <<= 8;` effectively multiplies `sample` by 256 but the third instance is relying on _undefined behavior_ to set the sign bit (bit 31). The `sample /= 1L << 12;` is dividing `sample` by 4096.

Comment: @AdrianMole Only the least significant 4 bits of the 3rd and final byte are lost. That is probably intentional because the samples are 20 bits wide.

Comment: @Ian Aha! OK - I skipped the final << 8 shift.

Comment: @AdrianMole Which doesn't make much sense, given the following operation...

Comment: @Bob it seems that the final 8-bit shift is to get the sign bit set according to the value of the first byte transferred. Then, the **division** is used, rather than a right-shift, to **avoid** undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's what I'm guessing too, but this is implementation defined at best, if I'm correct.

Comment: What is the return type of  `SPI.transfer(0)` and the range of values returned?

Comment: Looks like race condition bugs in the ISR of that code. Overall, you probably shouldn't be using some open source skunkware found on github...

Comment: Is the 20-bit value read padded with 4-bits in the MSbyte or  with the LSbyte?

Comment: The way I'm reading this, the three `|=` and `<<=` pairs read 24 bits into `sample` (resulting in a positive 24-bit value), then the last `/=` effectively shifts off the low 12 bits so you're left with a 12 bit value.  Not UB, but also not converting 20-bit 2's complement to 32 bit.

Comment: The part used appears to be ADS1230, a 20 bit delta sigma which uses big endian. This CPU is supposedly little endian. So I don't make any sense of the code at all.

Comment: it is C++ not C

Comment: @dbush If the 24 bit data read has the 20-bit 2's complement in the upper bits like Sxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxx0000, OP's code "works" with friendly UB.

Answer (score 1):

In general, bit-wise shift operations should be done on unsigned integer types because:

- Left-shifting a negative value results in undefined behavior.
- Left-shifting a non-negative, signed value results in undefined behavior if any non-zero bits are shifted to or through the position of the sign bit.
- Right-shifting a negative value produces an implementation-defined value.

If you are careful to avoid all of the above, bit-wise shift operations can be used portably on signed integer types as in the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
int32_t sample = 0;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample >>= 4;
// 'sample' contains a 20-bit, 2's complement value. Sign-extend to a 32-bit signed value.
if (sample >= (INT32_C(1) << 19))
    sample -= (INT32_C(1) << 20);
```

The `if (sample >= ...` sign-extension part might not be branch-free, depending on the compiler.  An alternative sign-extension conversion from 20-bit 2's complement to 32-bit signed is:

```
sample = (sample ^ (INT32_C(1) << 19)) - (INT32_C(1) << 20);
```

The XOR operation converts the 2's complement value to an offset binary value. That operation could be merged into the value of the byte from the first SPI transfer (the most significant 8 bits of the 20-bit sample value) as follows:

```
int32_t sample = 0;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0) ^ 0x80; // convert 2's complement to offset binary
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample >>= 4;
// 'sample' contains a 20-bit, offset binary value. Convert to 32-bit, signed value.
sample -= INT32_C(1) << 20;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> "Portably" here as long as `int32_t` is provided by the implementation. If not, then `int_least32_t` can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

> How this works?

If `SPI.transfer(0)` returns 0-255, it "works" when the 20-bit number is in the upper 24 bits of data read.  Then shifting that into the 32-bit type sign-bit relies on UB to form the correct value that when divided but `1 << 12` is the sought after value.

To convert a 20-bit 2's complement number to a `int32_t`, test the sign bit.

```
// Alternative without UB nor implementation defined behavior: 

int32_t sample = 0;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);
sample <<= 8;
sample |= SPI.transfer(0);

// if input is in upper 20 bits of the 24 read (OP is not explicit on that)
if (1) {
  sample >>= 4;
}

assert(sample >= 0 && sample <= 0xFFFFF);
if (sample & 0x80000) { // Test for the 20-bit 2's complement sign bit
  sample -= 0x100000;
}
```